# Complicated Cauchy complex integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the function $f(z)$ that defined on the closed disc $ \bar D_3(0)$
by the integeral on the boundry $C_3(0)$:

$f(z) = \int_{C_3(0)} \frac{3w^2+7w+1}{w-z}dw $

I need to find $f'(1+i)$

Caushy integral theorem and it`s conclusions tells me that on $C_3(0)$ boundry, my function is:

$f(w) = 2 \pi i(3w^2+7w+1)$ 
and that the derivative of $f(z)$ is:

$f'(z)=\int_{ C_3(0)}\frac {(3w^2+7w+1)}{(w-z)^2}dw$
we use $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb C  $ defined $ \gamma (t)=3e^{2\pi it}$ to be our path,
so we get:

$f'(1+i)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac {6 \pi ie^{2\pi i t}(3e^{4\pi it}+7e^{2\pi it}+1)}{(3e^{2\pi it}-(1+i))^2}dt$ as integral over a path is defined.

Is there  a way to pass over this complicated integral? or there is an algebric trick with whom I`ll solve this integral?, or maybe somehow to choose another parametrization to my path?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that $f(w) = 2\pi i (3w^2 + 7w + 1)$. Isn't it immediate that $f'(w) = 2 \pi i (6w + 7)$?

Comment: but this is only relevant on the boundry of the disc $D_3(0)$
when definitely 1+i is on the interior of $D_3(0)$